# Roslyn generic method specialization body

Tags: c#, generics, roslyn

Is possible to get Operations and/or Syntax Nodes for generic methods specialized with concrete types during invocation? So in sample below it will be `string` instead of `T`?

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Semantics;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace so
{
    internal class Walker : CSharpSyntaxWalker
    {
        public SemanticModel Model { get; set; }

        public override void VisitAssignmentExpression(AssignmentExpressionSyntax node)
        {
            var operation = (IAssignmentExpression)Model.GetOperation(node);
            if (operation.Value.Kind == OperationKind.InvocationExpression)
            {
                var invocation = (IInvocationExpression)operation.Value;
                foreach (
                    var syntax in
                    invocation.TargetMethod.DeclaringSyntaxReferences.Select(
                        x => (MethodDeclarationSyntax)x.GetSyntax()))
                {
                    var e = (TypeOfExpressionSyntax)syntax.ExpressionBody.Expression;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Generic type {invocation.TargetMethod.TypeParameters.First()} specialized with {invocation.TargetMethod.TypeArguments.First()}");
                    // How to get specialized body here? Currently it is just generic TypeParameters
                    var symbol = Model.GetSymbolInfo(e.Type).Symbol;
                    var typeofOperation = (ITypeOfExpression)Model.GetOperation(e);
                    Console.WriteLine($"{syntax.Identifier.Text} {symbol} {typeofOperation.TypeOperand}");
                }
            }
            base.VisitAssignmentExpression(node);
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
public class Program
{
    static Type TypeOf<T>() => typeof(T);

    public static void Main()
    {
        Type t;
        t = TypeOf<string>();
    }
}");
            var mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(null, new[] { tree }, new[] { mscorlib });
            var walker = new Walker { Model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree) };
            walker.Visit(tree.GetRoot());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Generic type T specialized with string
TypeOf T T
```

And I'm trying to get `TypeOf string string` in output.

Code on github - https://github.com/isanych/so-39447605

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that (directly).

Generic type substitution happens at the callsite, not the declaration.  There is no syntax tree that has your method body with a substituted `T`.

If you really want to do that, you'll need to manually replace `T` with its value from the callsite (and beware of all sorts of corner cases like name hiding, type parameters from base and/or enclosing classes, overload resolution, and worse).

Comment: Yes, type substitution happens at call, that is why I'm trying to get this information at invocation expression. And to perform substitution manually is a lot of work, which Roslyn already doing when generates IL for specialized functions - and I really don't want to do the same work :)

Comment: @ISanych That's not how generics in .Net work. In IL, there is only one version of the generic function, there are no specialized functions.

Comment: @svick you are right, I've got confused. I know that specialized classes are different types and assumed that methods also different there. I guess it is still the case, but it is JIT creating these specialized methods. And as IL generated only once it should be possible to get all operations with necessary level of details. So I only have to resolve all symbols in specialized implementation which is still non trivial as SLaks pointed out. I need to research this topic.